# [Vue warn]: Property or method "hp" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following code:

```
var example1;
var hp = ["p"];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  hp = ["x"];
  example1 = new Vue({
    el: '#example-1', //yes i have an element with #example-1 (not relevant here)
    data: {
      iLoveMyself: window.hp
    },
    
    watch: {
      iLoveMyself: {
        deep: true,
        immediate: true,
        handler (val, oldVal) {
          console.log("yeeeh")
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

I tried many things (that's why my code ^ is so damn ugly)  but i keep this console.error:

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "hp" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

If i look up the value in the chrome plugin for VueJs the the data set is as followed:

```
iLoveMyself:Array[1]
0:"x"
```

All good so far but when trying to update hp like:

```
hp.push("y");
hp.pop();
hp = "ZEBRA";
```

I get no response what so ever.

What is that i don't understand ?

Gratitude in advance!

**Edit:**
So after all i start to gather to pieces, my html is important after all :/

```
<div id="example-1">
  <div v-for="ev in hp" :key="ev.beavus">
    {{ ev.beavus }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error indicates that you're trying to use a property called `hp` in your template. However, you haven't defined a property called `hp` on your Vue instance. In the example code you have a property called `iLoveMyself`. You have a  variable called `hp` but that won't be accessible within the template, even if it is global. It needs to be a property of the instance or the template won't be able to see it.

Comment: please share the template

Comment: @skirtle i'm confused , gimme a moment please

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i made an edit

Comment: `v-for="ev in hp"` references `hp`. You need to change it to `iLoveMyself` to match the property on the instance. Either that or rename `iLoveMyself` to `hp`.

Comment: @skirtle i found that now, thanks for point me.
So i made my div#emaple-1 empty `<div id="example-1">
</div>`  to get rid of the error.

If i update "hp" still no update in the Vue instance

Comment: Thank you skirtle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more idiomatically Vue implementation of what you posted in the question:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',

  data: {
    iLoveMyself: [{beavus: "x"}]
  },

  watch: {
    iLoveMyself: {
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
      handler (val, oldVal) {
        console.log("yeeeh")
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    add () {
      this.iLoveMyself.push({beavus: Math.random()})
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example-1">
  <div v-for="ev in iLoveMyself" :key="ev.beavus">
    {{ ev.beavus }}
  </div>
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
</div>
```

I've got rid of the global variables, there's now just an instance property called `iLoveMyself` that holds the array. Pushing extra data to the array triggers both the `watch` and updates the DOM with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
<div id="example-1">
  <div v-for="ev in iLoveMyself" :key="ev.beavus">
    {{ ev.beavus }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that did get rid of the error, still when updating the var hp i get no response

Comment: that property is not reactive, please precise your use case and we hope find a way that respects the paradigm of Vue

Comment: I think using observable fits to your case check this article https://vuedose.tips/tips/creating-a-store-without-vuex-in-vue-js-2-6/